# Plot Square Wave in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

Im currently working on graphing a square wave in python using numpy and pylot.
How would I plot a square wave function over multiple periods of T?

I currently have:

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft

#Initialize Parameters
p_0 = 2
A = np.sqrt(1/(2*p_0))
t = [-A,A]


plt.plot(t,[A,A])
plt.show()
```

which just gives me a straight line.
The end game is to take the Fourier transform of the square wave function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `square` function from `scipy.signal`

```py
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 500, endpoint=False)
plt.plot(t, signal.square(2 * np.pi * 5 * t),'b')
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: how would I change the period of the wave?

Answer (score 1):

This code below will do the trick:

```
import math, numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = numpy.array([1 if math.floor(2 * t) % 2 == 0 else 0 for t in x])

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

- If the `math.floor(2 * t) % 2 == 0` returns `True` plot `1` else plot `0`.

Output:
[image]